# How to vectorize Matlab Code with mvnpdf in?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have some working code in matlab, and speed is vital. I have **vectorized/optimized** many parts of it, and the profiler now tells me that the most time is spent a short piece of code. For this,

- I have some parameter sets for a **multi-variate normal
  distribution**.
- I then have to get the value from the corresponding PDF at some point
  pos,
- and multiply it by some other value stored in a vector.

I have produced a minimal working example below:

```
num_params = 1000;
prob_dist_params = repmat({ [1, 2], [10, 1; 1, 5] }, num_params, 1);
saved_nu  = rand( num_params, 1 );
saved_pos = rand( num_params, 2 );
saved_total = 0;
tic()
for param_counter = 1:size(prob_dist_params)
    % Evaluate the PDF at specified points
    pdf_vals = mvnpdf( saved_pos(param_counter,:), prob_dist_params{param_counter,1}, prob_dist_params{param_counter, 2} );
    saved_total = saved_total + saved_nu(param_counter)*pdf_vals;
end % End of looping over parameters
toc()
```

I am aware that `prob_dist_params` are all the same in this case, but in my code we have each element of this different depending on a few things upstream. I call this particular piece of code many tens of thousands of time in my full program, so am wondering if there is anything at all I can do to **vectorize this loop**, or failing that, **speed it up at all**? I do not know how to do so with the inclusion of a **`mvnpdf()`** function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, however, I don't think it will give you a huge performance boost. You will have to reshape your `mu`'s and `sigma`'s.

Checking the doc of [`mvnpdf(X,mu,sigma)`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnpdf.html#d117e574691), you see that you will have to provide `X` and `mu` as *n*-by-*d* numeric matrix and `sigma` as *d*-by-*d*-by-*n*.

In your case, *d* is 2 and *n* is 1000. You have to split the cell array in two matrices, and reshape as follows:

```
prob_dist_mu = cell2mat(prob_dist_params(:,1));
prob_dist_sigma = cell2mat(permute(prob_dist_params(:,2),[3 2 1]));
```

With `permute`, I make the first dimension of the cell array the third dimension, so `cell2mat` will result in a 2-by-2-by-1000 matrix. Alternatively you can define them as follows,

```
prob_dist_mu = repmat([1 2], [num_params 1]);
prob_dist_sigma = repmat([10, 1; 1, 5], [1 1 num_params]);
```

Now call `mvnpdf` with

```
pdf_vals = mvnpdf(saved_pos, prob_dist_mu, prob_dist_sigma);
saved_total = saved_nu.'*pdf_vals;     % simple dot product
```

Comment: Thanks, this is marginally faster depending on array size, but any speed up is useful.